# update my python version to 3.6. conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, conda, updates

I can't update my python version to 3.6.
i tried:
`conda update python`
`conda install python==3.6`

also tried to create new environment
`conda create --name py36 python=3.6`

i tried downloading the .exe installer from site and checked the option to apply path variables.
even then it was of no use.
whatever i do , i keep getting the same error as sown in snip

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1InC.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conda install -c anaconda python=3.6` to update Python.

But may I ask why you choose 3.6 over 3.8? `conda install -c anaconda python=3.8` will get you the newest release.

Comment: did not help.it kept on reolving the environment.Thank you very much for the help anyway.